# Count word written in textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, textarea, word-count

I am trying to count the number of times a keyword from input field is used throughout a text that user have written in a textarea. I kinda made it work but having some issues. How can I make the search do live search instead of as it is now, where user have to push a button in order for the code to search?

```
$(function() {
  function numHits(n, h) {
    var c, re = new RegExp(n, "g");
    c = (h.match(re) || []).length;
    return c;
  }
  $("#finder").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#keyword-count").html(numHits($("#keyword-input").val(), $("#my-txt-area").val()));
  });
});
```

```
<form id="finder">
  <textarea name="mytxtarea" id="my-txt-area" cols="100" rows="10"></textarea>
  <br>
  <div class="input-area" id="div-keywords">
    <input type="text" id="keyword-input" placeholder="Enter keyword..." /> <button id="search-keyword" type="submit">Search</button>
  </div>
</form>
<p>Your word has been used <span id="keyword-count">0</span> times throughout the text.</p>
```

[Code Snippet](https://jsfiddle.net/5ncxw3df/)

Comment: You can listen for the [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input) event instead of `click`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to place the function on keyup event of your query box

```
$(function() {
  function numHits(n, h) {
    var c, re = new RegExp(n, "g");
    c = (h.match(re) || []).length;
    return c;
  }
  $("#keyword-input").keyup(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#keyword-count").html(numHits($("#keyword-input").val(), $("#my-txt-area").val()));
  });
});
```

Comment: Hi @sc0rp1on. I've tried the solution you provided but doesn't seem to work for me: https://jsfiddle.net/h2ctqseL/

Comment: @TobiasM it is working. Please notice the number changes as soon as you press a key.
You have a to place a check for it to not change when the field is empty